# Custom Conditional formatting via a macro

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I found something interesting: Activate the macro recorder. Create a condtional formatting rule from "Start -> conditional formatting -> new rule". Just any rule is sufficient. Only press "ok" NOT apply! This is very important, apply doesn't have the same effect for me. End the macro recorder.

Now you have a macro where ALL your conditional formatting rules are present in VBA code. Very handy, if you want to tweak or apply them.

Now I want to make this whole process more user friendly. The user is capable of using the standard way of creating a rule. Now I want to shorten this process.

Is there any way to record the macro recorder? Basically triggering the button from a macro. I could easily recreate the steps above then.
Any other ways? Can I use a UserForm and somehow the rules are puleld from custom fields?
Any ideas how to push this task further? I don't know where to start.

Comment: It does. I already thought there will be only limited functionality without add-ins etc. I'll see what I can do with this, thanks!